# Bottom navbar isn't showing when pdf is displayed in Xamarin forms webview for ios

Tags: c#, xamarin.forms, webview

My goal is to be able to download a PDF from a site displayed in a Xamarin.Forms webview for iOS.

My issue is the following:
I connect to a mobile site from the safari browser on an iPhone, I click on a PDF link (blob_url), safari shows the PDF and at the bottom of the screen I have a navigation bar to do back or download the PDF:

I do exactly the same treatment but loading the site in Webview Xamarin.Forms for iOS, the PDF is displayed but impossible to have the bottom navigation bar which is needed to download the PDF.

I made some modifications in the rederer, hybridwebview, I even went to see the code of the renderer in the Github of Xamarin.Forms, I did not find solutions.

I absolutely have to make it work this way, through a webview.

Thanks for your help.

Comment: I think your idea about the `WebView` control is wrong. It shows you only a page, the toolbar at the bottom is Safari, that is not the `WebView`. So, you will either have to implement your own kind of toolbar _or_ maybe you can open the in-app browser control with Xamarin.Essentials that might have the toolbar you're looking for.